# disable first level cache in Spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My project has two applications. One is API Module the other is  Backend Management.They use the same database,I use spring boot 1.3.7 with data jpa 1.9.4 and hibernate 4.3.11 .API is http restful endpoint for user to login and do with their business.Management System is to maintain the data of system. These is a problem when I insert new data through Management UI,the API Module can not retrieve the data immediately until about 5 minutes later.One scenario is when i add a new user in backend,in API , the method `findByUsername` will not get the username i add just now.Is there any idea to slove this problem?Any suggestions will be appreciated!

**API**

```
package com.brahalla.Cerberus.service.impl;

import com.brahalla.Cerberus.domain.entity.User;
import com.brahalla.Cerberus.model.factory.CerberusUserFactory;
import com.brahalla.Cerberus.model.security.CerberusUser;
import com.brahalla.Cerberus.repository.UserRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  /**
   * API :findByUsername
   */
  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (user == null) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("No user found with username '%s'.", username));
    } else {
      return CerberusUserFactory.create(user);
    }
  }

}
```

**Backend Management**

```
package com.brahalla.Cerberus.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.brahalla.Cerberus.domain.entity.User;
import com.brahalla.Cerberus.repository.UserRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    /**
     * Backend add new user
     * 
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(User user) {
        user.setId(null);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
package com.brahalla.Cerberus.repository;

import com.brahalla.Cerberus.domain.entity.User;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  public User findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Comment: 5 mins is too mush of a time, when you are working on same DB for R/W operations, also even if we user master/slave topology, replication, still 5 mins looks too much of a time. Pls put some code to analyze further, Can you please show us the sample code with class/package imports where you are writing and reading from DB, just for example of user.

Comment: Disabling the L1 cache is a dumb idea, even assuming your JPA provider allows it

Comment: I have add the sample code above. the two sample code are from two module,API and Backend.which mean two *.war will be packaged. But R/W database is the same.**I think the real problem of my question is how to retrieve the new data when i insert/update data outside jpa eg.Navicat Client**

Comment: please see above @AnkurSinghal

Comment: @phxism pls add `UserRepository`

Comment: UserRepository is just a simple interface which extends spring data jpa . think the real problem of my question is how to retrieve the new data when i insert/update data outside jpa eg.Navicat Client @AnkurSinghal

Comment: @phxism within this 5 min time lag, can you actually see the record in your DB inserted..??

Comment: yes . I use Navicat to see that data is realtime updated/inserted. but because insert and find are in two applications even though using same DB.so hibernate's shared entityManager will not know the first level cached data is old ,thus, api system can not retrieve the new data updated/inserted by manage system right now. Maybe 5+minutes later, hibernate session caches timeout, it will get latest data from DB @AnkurSinghal

Comment: @phxism you are mixing the 2 things, if you have talked about updating user, then there can be an issue, but insertion of new record should work fine..??

Comment: I hope so,but the truth is when I insert new record,it still cannot get new data.Unless i restart tomcat or reresh spring context of api module.so i replace `userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user " + username));`
 with `userRepository.findAll().stream().filter(x -> x.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)).findAny().orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user " + username))`  findAll can get new data updated/inserted from manangement system.@AnkurSinghal

Comment: You cannot disable first level caching as the 1st level cache IS the `EntityManager` .. If you cannot see your data you are doing things in a weird way especially if they are in the same database. so there is no 1st level caching issue I suspect the problem is in your application. Your `UserRepository.save` should be done from a `@Transactional` service method and not directly in the controller.

Comment: If cache related this is 2nd level or query cache. See the hibernate documentation how to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but **first level cache cannot be disabled**.

Comment: thanks for reply,but in other way, is there other way such as 'change the session timeout time', waiting 5 or 5+minutes is too long